# Как заменить пакет nuget на dll в большом солюшене

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, asp.net, nuget

Мне нужно внести изменения в большой (действительно большой) солюшен. Для этого мне нужно изменить код в кастомном пакете NuGet, используемом проектами в солюшене.

Но я не могу создать измененную версию пакета в NuGet фиде, а затем просто обновить ее в солюшене.

У меня есть доступ к репозиторию пакета, поэтому у меня есть dll с необходимыми изменениями.

Итак, вопрос: как с минимальными усилиями заменить NuGet этой dll? Когда я попытался просто заменить необходимую библиотеку NuGet в папке пакетов на измененную, это привело к тому, что солюшен не сбилдился.

Любая помощь приветствуется.

Comment: `Но я не могу создать измененную версию пакета в NuGet фиде`, а можете новый пакет создать и перевести солюшен на него?

Comment: Можно попробовать локальный нюгет фид поднять: https://spin.atomicobject.com/2021/01/05/local-nuget-package/

Comment: Просто заменить библиотеку нельзя, потому что она на следующем restore замениться назад. Тут нужно применить то что предложил Ssss, но фокус в том, что для одного пакета нельзя выбрать источник. Поэтому если вы меняете источник на локальный, ВСЕ пакеты нужно переводить на него.